# How can I ask for clarification on a question I'd like to answer if I can't add comments?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

I've been trying to break the 15 barrier for about 2 years now (much less the 50 barrrier!), and I want to try and answer this question:

[When deleting item list from list, last remaining item won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482192/when-deleting-item-list-from-list-last-remaining-item-wont-go-away)

But the question needs some clarification before I can answer it. How can I get this clarification if I can't post a comment? Or do I just have to sit this one out?

Comment: Yep. You'll simply have to gain enough rep. It really shouldn't be all that hard. There are several ways to gain some. You could edit that question into shape for example. If that edit gets accepted, you get 2 rep. And it could certainly do with some editing.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I'll have a go at that.

Comment: (It seems that asking this here kind of solved it too for you `;-)`)

Comment: oh wow - I don't totally understand the magic, it would appear that my reputation is now high enough to contribute a bit more now. thank you!

Comment: If the clarification needed is a minor one and you can sort of guess at what is meant, you can post an answer like "Assuming you meant XXXX, the answer would be..." If it's a good answer it'll probably get upvoted :-)

Comment: @Bennidhamma The magic is exposure. By asking on meta, you made people aware of there being someone trying to be helpful, and doing that in the right way, not just posting their clarification requests as an answer. So people checked your profile and some upvoted posts they deemed good. If your posts had been terrible, you'd have gotten a number of downvotes instead.

Comment: I was so intimidated by the process. As you can see, my efforts over the last two years have been fairly minimal - I guess I just never really grokked that this is a community of real people, who want to create a helpful environment, even though I probably come here 10 - 20 times a day. It feels good to have learned a little bit more about this community today. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 10):

**You don't.**

There are plenty of other questions - find one you *can* answer, and answer it. Not only is this going to be easier for you, but it rewards the folks who *do* take time to put enough detail in their questions up front.

**Alternately**... *Guess*. If there's an interpretation of the author's words that indicate a question you *can* answer, post that answer - and prefix it with an explanation ("Your question is a bit unclear, but if you mean ... then ..."). This is a gamble - if you guess wrong, you probably won't get anything for your trouble, and the question may even be closed and deleted! But if you're right and it pays off, you skip the tedious wait for a response that comes with asking for clarification. If you want to be *extra-daring*, edit the question to clarify it after answering...